# EEVEE viewport and procedural materials

Tags: materials

Is it possible to use procedural textured materials in the blender 2.80 EEVEE viewport?

Are the procedural maps that come with Blender 2.80 enough to compose any material?

Are there procedural map plugins that I can get?

Comment: Please ask only one question at a time. Give us some info on what you struggle with, and what you have tried so far to get the result you want. As the question stands, the answer would be "yes, no and kind of", which doesn't provide a ton of value to anyone.

Comment: I was wondering if the procedural textures that work in Blender render work in EEVEE too?
Yes or no ?

Comment: yes, they do, but things like displacement and vector displacement nodes don't work in Eevee.